# Google Cloud SQL Proxy issues passing credentials file

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

From the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-docker#tcp-sockets) :

```
docker run -d \
  -v <PATH_TO_KEY_FILE>:/config \
  -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 \
  gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16 /cloud_sql_proxy \
  -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 -credential_file=/config
```

My version

```
docker run -d \
    -v ssh-master-account-key.json:/config \
    -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 \
    gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16 /cloud_sql_proxy \
    -instances=mvp-api-254102:us-central1:mvp-api=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 -credential_file=/config
```

Unfortunately Docker complains:

```
invalid json file "/config": read /config: is a directory
```

This seems to be such a simple thing to do yet I can't figure it out. Any clues?

Comment: The entry `/config` is a directory that already exists in your container. Try specifying another name.

Comment: I tried that as the first thing but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct form:

```
docker run -d \
    -v /Users/<user>/Code/mvp/mvp-server/scripts/credentials:/config \
    -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 \
    gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16 /cloud_sql_proxy \
    -instances=mvp-api-254102:us-central1:mvp-api=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 -credential_file=/config/ssh-master-account-key.json
```

Comment: Is credentials.json file your service account key or some other file? 
Because I am trying with my service account key and yet I get 403 error